# how can i use watchPositionAsync in useFocusEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

**i tried to use this code**

```
    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
            const getLocation = async() => {
                await getPermissionsAsync()
                const subscribe = await watchPositionAsync({
                accuracy:Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
                timeInterval:5000
                },(location) => {console.log(1)})
                return () => subscribe.remove()
            }

            return getLocation()
        }, [])
      );
```

**but i get this error**

- An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. It looks like you wrote 'useFocusEffect(async () => ...)' or returned a Promise. Instead, write the
  async function inside your effect and call it immediately:
- 

```
 useFocusEffect(
   React.useCallback() => {
     async function fetchData() {
       // You can await here
     const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
       // ...
     }

     fetchData();
   }, [someId])
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

```
useFocusEffect(
  useCallback(() => {
    let subcription;
    const getLocation = async() => {
      await getPermissionsAsync()
      subcription = await watchPositionAsync({
        accuracy:Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
        timeInterval:5000
      }, (location) => {console.log(1)})
    }
    getLocation();
    return () => { subscription && subscription.remove(); }
  }, [])
);
```

The error actually says what needs to occur. that is the return value must be a simple function used for cleanup.

The subscription is obtained as part of an `async` call in the `getLocation` function, but for it to be used it must be pulled out and have it set asynchronously.

Then the cleanup function just needs to check if it is already set and if it is invoke the remove method.